# SQL Server 2008 multiple column filter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have stuck on sql query to bring the wanted data. I have table as following
[image]

I have tried cte table but did not work . I need the get source 'O' if available else 'T' with max sequence as above result table.

```
select district
     , id
     , building
     , year
     , date
     , period
     , sequence
     , source from GetAttData gt with (nolock) where sequence in (select max(sequence) from GetAttData with (nolock)
                where district = gt.district 
                    and building = gt.building 
                    and year = gt.year
                    and id= gt.id
                group by district, id, building, year, date, period)
    and source =  'O'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select
  district, id, building, year, date, period, sequence, source
from (
  select district, id, building, year, date, period, sequence, source,
  row_number() over(partition by district, id, building, year, date, period
                    order by case when source = 'O' then 0 else 1 end, sequence desc
                   ) as takeme
) foo
where takeme = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gserg, you save my day.